# What's the severest punishment giving to the rapists according to Islamic laws?

Tags: punishment, hudud

After a miserable and completely heartbreaking incident happened in Kathua, J&K, India, I would ask question that, in this case, what punishment does Allah(swt) give which is defined in the Islamic laws?

As Allah(swt) is for everyone, please don't think this question as religion-specific, but in general what can be the most severest punishment given to the culprits?

Someone reading the question who is unaware about the news can read [from here](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-43722714) by BBC.

Comment: Rape is variously classified as Zina or Hirabah. The punishment for Hirabah is in [5:33](https://quran.com/5/33).

Comment: India doesn't apply shariah law in it's civil courts, I'm not sure of the intent behind this question.